# this undefined when calling function of parent inside ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Angular 4.

A user list component displays a list of user detail components. Whenever a detail is changed, the list must be notified. This works through an output on the detail. But when the list listener is called, `this` is undefined, therefore I cannot access any list state.

```
<!-- list template -->
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let user of users">
    <user-detail [user]="user" (onChanged)="onChanged()"></user-detail>
  </li>
</ul>

// list listener
public onChanged(): void {
  this.whatever = 'something else'; // boom! this undefined
}
```

How do I need to setup the list component for this to work?

I remember from AngularJS 1 that ngFor created new scopes for items and hence I needed to use `$parent`. But how does this work for Angular 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the problem on [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ULv76j36Fmc8aO3curUv?p=preview), but I was unable to so, everything worked as expected. Then I noticed the difference between the working minimal example and the buggy code. It was the chaining of a Promise where I lost context:

```
this.asyncThing().then(this.onChanged);
```

The `this` context is correctly set when calling the function explicitly:

```
this.asyncThing().then(() => this.onChanged());
```

My bad.

Answer (score 1):

You should have an input property on your user-detail child component

UserDetailComponent

```
@Input() user: User;

ngOnChanges() {
  console.log(this.user);
}
```

You need not have a method explicitly

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let user of users">
    <user-detail [user]="user"></user-detail>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Explanation: When ever an input property of any component is changed, the `ngOnChanges()` life cycle hook is triggered automatically.

Comment: what is your expectation and your code below seems to be spaghetti